# Vue 2.0 and SemanticUI progress bars

Tags: vuejs2, semantic-ui

I am new to VueJS and I have a very simple to solve problem I suppose...

I have a simple component to wrap a SemanticUI progress bar:

```
<template>
     <div class="column">
          <div class="ui orange inverted progress" v-bind:data-percent="progress" id="loading-bar">
                <div class="bar"></div>

                <div class="label">{{ label }}</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
     export default {
          mounted() {
                window.$('#loading-bar').progress();
          },
          props: ['label', 'progress'],
          updated() {
                console.log(this._props.progress);
          },
     };
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Its parent component (with probably irrelevant sections snipped out) looks like this:

```
<template>
     <v-layout>
          <v-load-def label="Logging in..." :progress="test"></v-load-def>
     </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
     import store from '@/store';

     export default {
          data() {
                return {
                     test: 1,
                };
          },
          mounted() {
                store.dispatch('account/initialLoad1').then(() => {
                     console.log(this);
                     this.test = 20;
                     store.dispatch('account/initialLoad2').then(() => {
                          this.test = 60;
                          store.dispatch('account/initialLoad3').then(() => {
                                this.test = 100;
                          });
                     });
                });
          },
          components: {
                VLoadDef: require('@/components/load-def.vue'),
          },
     };
</script>
```

While 'account/initialLoadX' just delay using a setTimeout. Now the debug output in the progress bar component's updated hook

```
console.log(this._props.progress);
```

tells me, that the property is correctly updated after the delayed calls. However the progress bar ignores any changes. I even tried a

```
window.$('#loading-bar').progress(this._props.progress);
```

after this debug output for testing purposes (I take it this._props is not supposed to be used) - still no effect.

So what am doing wrong? Did I misunderstood the reactiveness of Vue or the way SemanticUI progress bars work? I looked for examples in SemanticUI-VueJS-binding libraries but they conveniently left out progress bars ;)

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Semantic UI, but I was able to build a small component that might point you in the right direction.

Basically in order to get the bar to progress, I had to call the `progress` plugin with the new percentage whenever the property updated. To do that I created a method that calls it, and call the method both in `mounted` and from  a `watch`.

```
Vue.component("v-progress", {
  template: "#bar-template",
  props:["label", "progress"],
  methods:{
    udpateProgress(){
       $(this.$refs.progress).progress({
        percent: this.progress
      });   
    }
  },
  watch:{
    progress(newVal){
      this.udpateProgress() 
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.udpateProgress()
  }
})
```

Here is a [working demo](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jLNrma?editors=1010).

Comment: Not only works, but I also learned $refs not only works on child components but on all elements with a ref attribute. Thank you!